# Can't pass completed array through completion handler or any other way using Firebase observe method

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to use a completion handler to pass an array of the data from the Firebase database using the observe method, it only passes the first item in the database (or none at all when I try other ways). The only way that I have found that works for passing an array of all the data in Firebase's database is by using a timer, which is poor practice. How do I pass along a completed array of the data on Firebase database?

Here's my code:

```
func loadHighScore(completionHandler:@escaping (_ scoresArray: [User]?)->()) {
    ref.child("Scores").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        var scoresArray:[User] = []
        let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
        let username = dictionary["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let score = dictionary["High Score"] as? Int ?? 0
        let user = User(username: username, highScore: score)
        scoresArray.append(user)
        completionHandler(scoresArray)
    }, withCancel: {(err) in
        print("Error downloading profile: \(err)")
        completionHandler(nil)
    })
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
Firebase.sharedInstance.loadHighScore() { users in
    guard let users = users else { return }
    print("users: \(users)")
    self.sortedUsers = users.sorted {
        $0.highScore > $1.highScore
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The console shows one user being printed at a time instead of an array of users. The tableview displays only one user instead of all of them. When I try to use a for in loop with the completion handler called outside the for in loop, I get an error about how I can't use a for in loop.

How do I get around using a timer to get a completed array passed to the function that calls my observe Firebase function?

Comment: Can you also add a screen of your firebase data? Because in code it seems that you're adding only one user to the array that you're passing on completion...

Comment: I tried adding a screenshot of my firebase database by dropping it into a place for images, but then it doesn't add to my post. So I don't know how to add a screenshot.

Comment: Try following this [Answer in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're accessing only one user on snapshot, so try this code below

```
 func loadHighScore(completionHandler:@escaping (_ scoresArray: [User]?)->()) {
        ref.child("Scores").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var scoresArray:[User] = []
            for userSnap in snapshot.children {
                 guard let userSnapshot = userSnap as? FIRDataSnapshot else { 
                     return completion(scoresArray) // this will be empty array
                 }
                 let dictionary = userSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
                 let username = dictionary["Username"] as? String ?? ""
                 let score = dictionary["High Score"] as? Int ?? 0
                 let user = User(username: username, highScore: score)
                 scoresArray.append(user)
            }
            completionHandler(scoresArray)
        }, withCancel: {(err) in
            print("Error downloading profile: \(err)")
            completionHandler(nil)
        })
    }
```

Comment: That looks promising, but when I try your code I get this error for "user.value": Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Comment: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Comment: That yields this error for the guard statement: Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I think it should work now, after this edit right now, try again with my edited answer, copy paste the code, because I made a few changes

Comment: Happy to help :D Don't forget to accept it as the correct answer!